# App crashes when running on phone, runs fine on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CIRCGy2.png]

Above is the sole error I get. Usually this happens to me when theres a reference to a button that doesn't exist. The problem is that it would crash in the sim as well if that was the case. It runs perfectly fine in the simulator as mentioned, however crashes when I test it on my iPhone. The only thing that I can think of off the bat is that the sdk is for 8.4 and I'm on 8.1.

Crash log

http://pastebin.com/fhFr4eBz

Buttons

```
@IBAction func topButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var nicebutton = sender as! UIButton

    nicebutton.enabled = false

    var nopebutton = nicebutton.superview?.viewWithTag(102) as! UIButton

    nopebutton.enabled = true

    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count")
    object.save()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([hitIndex!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}


@IBAction func bottomButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var nopebutton = sender as! UIButton

    nopebutton.enabled = false

    var nicebutton = nopebutton.superview?.viewWithTag(101) as! UIButton

    nicebutton.enabled = true
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: -1)
    object.saveInBackground()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([hitIndex!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}
```

Edit - Quick thanks to you guys on here for the help the past few days. You've really helped me take an idea in my head to the physical. Kudos to those that broke things down for me.

Comment: show your crash log from console.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni http://pastebin.com/fhFr4eBz

Comment: Add that into your question.

Comment: Often product->clean works.  Also what is your button doing?  Can you give us any relevant code?

Comment: Are you trying to access a variable or method that isn't available on the OS version that the physical device is using?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I'll add them in. Theyre just voting buttons.

Comment: Try adding a println() at every line and see where the app crashes

Comment: @Jojodmo I'm under the impression that might be the issue. I'll have to update to 8.4, but before that I'd like to know if there's a glaring issue.

Comment: @JamesChen I don't see any looking at it, but the way you're getting subviews seems pretty unsafe. Try declaring the subviews globally and using that variable instead of using things like `nopebutton.superview?.viewWithTag(101)`. Also, maybe store `object` globally in a map `[:]` too, if possible

Answer (score 0):

I think you have crash because you reloading table view in a wrong way

You should reload it like this

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([hitIndex!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fun. The whole reason why this code broke is because I tried to hide the tabbar globally on the appdelegate. My phone hated that with a passion and just refused to start. I've had to redo it from scratch to find that out.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Apple. Unfortunately this is how it goes and they will always break things in new versions to make it even more "interesting". If you're lucky, you'll get a stack dump. Not always even that.